# Farm outgoing email multiple addresses

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, email, central-administration, outgoing-email

Is it possible in SP2013 to configure multiple email accounts for the outgoing email?

I wish to have one email address for each web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can.

- Go to the `Central Admin > Application management > Web Application
  >Manage Web Application`
- Click on the Web Application(which email address you want to change) and from Ribbion Click on the Setting Drop down and Hit Outgoing-Email.
- On Pop up you can enter outgoing email address.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can configure outgoing email per web application. Navigate to "Manage web application" from central administration -> Select a web application -> Clcik on the General settings **DROPDOWN** from the top ribbon and you can set the outgoing email settings for the web application there.

You still need to have your default farm level settings in place. Refer [this](http://sharepointgeorge.com/2010/configuring-outgoing-email-sharepoint-2010/)

> Did you know that you can also configure outgoing email for a specific Web application?  You might want to do this if you have multiple SharePoint Web Applications hosting specific site collections and would want a different From and or Reply Address setup.
>
> Even though we are now going to configure outgoing email for a
>   specific Web application, you are still required to setup the default
>   farm outgoing email settings as per the above.